# How to get form data from html text field using php get method and write it to a txt file?

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="" method="get">
<div id= "window"><center><input id="chatbox" type="text" name="chatbox">
<br></center></div> 

</form>

<?php

$myfile = fopen("chat.txt", "a+") 
$chattext = $_GET['chatbox'];
fwrite($myfile, $chattext);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I have looked at other solutions but for some reason I can't make my code work. My goal is to take the text in the text field and write it to the chat.txt file. I am very new to php so it is definitely possible that I just made a stupid syntax error. Thank You for your help.

Comment: Make sure the file has all the necessary permissions.

Comment: What error do you have? Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `$myfile = fopen('chat.txt', 'a+');
$chattext = $_GET['chatbox']==='' ? $_GET['chatbox'] : 'Hellow';
fwrite($myfile, $chattext);
fclose($myfile);`  fixed

Comment: @Teocci sorry about that I tried to be as specific as possible in my question I am not getting any errors which is a major problem as I can't really see if my code is even running. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Did you tried the code that I post before? I corrected your syntax error. Please check if is so I will post it as an answer to close your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You forgot the `;` after `fopen()`
- I modified the code with an if statement
- I added new line after each insert

**Updated code:**

```
<form action="" method="get">

<div id= "window"><center><input id="chatbox" type="text" name="chatbox">
<br></center></div> 

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['chatbox'])){
    $myfile = fopen("chat.txt", "a+") ;
    $chattext = $_GET['chatbox'].PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($myfile, $chattext);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```

Comment: That is a very silly error! Hahaha but I still seem to have a problem is it possible that I am calling the php wrong as it still is not running. Is it a problem that I have it in an html file not a php because I tried it in both and in both cases it did not work.

Comment: the file with php content should be a php file of course not html.. this code is works, I've tested it. If you get another problem you should us what is the error

Comment: this is embarrassing but I have no idea how to call this code I think that may have been my original problem. I have tried some solutions online but I can't seem to understand what goes where when I put the code into a php file and then created a button to link to it when I clicked the button I was taken to a page that just displayed the code. So then I tried to put the whole thing in a php file and that just plum didn't work I'm sorry but how do I make this even run?

Comment: Do you use WAMP, LAMP? Or what kind of environment do you use?

Comment: I have just been using notepad++ to code in.

Comment: Not to code, to run the code? installed apache with php or?

Comment: Oh sorry XAMPP.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter realized my mistake and was able to make it work you were a godsend!

Comment: Colud you close the question or accept the answer?